# What could be the interpretation of these strace outputs?

Tags: linux, strace, busy-waiting, ltrace

I have a problem with a calculus software in Linux (Ubuntu 20.04). When I submit a calculus, the work is performed perfectly. The log file indicates that everything was completed successfully and all the results are perfect.

The problem arises when I try to submit another calculus: the numerical modulus stills busy. So, I traced the PID of the process with `strace -p PID`. This is the output:

```
restart_syscall(<... resuming interrupted read ...>) = 0
clock_nanosleep(CLOCK_REALTIME, 0, {tv_sec=2, tv_nsec=0}, 0x7fff57f793a0) = 0
clock_nanosleep(CLOCK_REALTIME, 0, {tv_sec=2, tv_nsec=0}, 0x7fff57f793a0) = 0
clock_nanosleep(CLOCK_REALTIME, 0, {tv_sec=2, tv_nsec=0}, 0x7fff57f793a0) = 0
clock_nanosleep(CLOCK_REALTIME, 0, {tv_sec=2, tv_nsec=0}, 0x7fff57f793a0) = 0
clock_nanosleep(CLOCK_REALTIME, 0, {tv_sec=2, tv_nsec=0}, 0x7fff57f793a0) = 0
clock_nanosleep(CLOCK_REALTIME, 0, {tv_sec=2, tv_nsec=0}, 0x7fff57f793a0) = 0
clock_nanosleep(CLOCK_REALTIME, 0, {tv_sec=2, tv_nsec=0}, 0x7fff57f793a0) = 0
clock_nanosleep(CLOCK_REALTIME, 0, {tv_sec=2, tv_nsec=0}, 0x7fff57f793a0) = 0
clock_nanosleep(CLOCK_REALTIME, 0, {tv_sec=2, tv_nsec=0}, 0x7fff57f793a0) = 0
```

And it goes on to infinite printing `clock_nanosleep(CLOCK_REALTIME, 0, {tv_sec=2, tv_nsec=0}, 0x7fff57f793a0) = 0`

Is there some useful information? What could this result be saying?